# How to exec the two contracts one has the another address

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, truffle, ganache

I deployed contracts `first` and `second` with this script.

And I want to test this contract on `truffle console`.

However error comes.

`first.sol`

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract First{
    int public mydata;
    function GetDouble(int _data) public returns(int _output){
        mydata= _data * 2;
        return _data * 2;
    }
}
```

`second.sol`

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;
import "./first.sol";
contract Second{
    address firstAddress;
    int public _data;
    constructor(address _first) public{
        firstAddress = _first;
    }
    function SetData() public{
        First h = First(firstAddress);
        _data = h.GetDouble(21);
    }
}
```

`3_Custom.js`

```
var hw = artifacts.require("First");
var hw1 = artifacts.require("Second");
module.exports = function(deployer){
    deployer.deploy(hw).then
    (function(){
        return deployer.deploy(hw1,hw.address);
    })
};
```

Now I want to try this script on `truffle console`.

```
truffle(development)> Second.address
'0xf3b9059123028a9e77f8dd3fe53b64f2e5680b80'

truffle(development)> var s = Second.at(Second.address)

truffle(development)> s.SetData(2)
Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-contract/contract.js:204:1
    at SolidityFunction.execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/function.js:256:1)
    at SolidityFunction.sendTransaction (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/function.js:163:1)
    at SolidityFunction.toPayload (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/function.js:90:1)
    at SolidityFunction.validateArgs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/function.js:74:1)
    at Object.InvalidNumberOfSolidityArgs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:25:1)
```

---

I use `s.setData()` , it returns

```
{ tx:
   '0x279aa09f95a4f96520d7d2dab2a0a3c923b7e17c393496be08ba52e89a376970',
  receipt:
   { transactionHash:
      '0x279aa09f95a4f96520d7d2dab2a0a3c923b7e17c393496be08ba52e89a376970',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash:
      '0x5d0cb4929292dba726af031736d39b8521669f2c8f470186da960ba30f61063a',
     blockNumber: 7,
     from: '0xf20bd17dccd1e442141f7b9d93f1c8f366fc7f94',
     to: '0x771939ec841204dd071fe5f3d35267461c4c2109',
     gasUsed: 25645,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 25645,
     contractAddress: null,
     logs: [],
     status: '0x1',
     logsBloom:
      '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' },
  logs: [] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
truffle(development)> s.SetData(2)
Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function
```

You're trying to pass an argument to the `SetData` function, but its definition (in the `Second` contract) contains 0 arguments:

```
function SetData() public{
```

Comment: THank you very much  , I use `s.SetData()`